# How to segment lan

Tags: routing, firewall, lan

I have a LAN 10.0.0.0/255.255.252.0 (10.0.0.0-10.0.3.255) and want to separate clients (10.0.3.x) from the servers (10.0.0.x and 10.0.1.x) with a firewall in front of the servers.
My problem is, i cant change address ranges nor subnets.
Is this doable?

Thanks.

Edit: @HAL I looked up on vlsm and it looks exactly like what I need. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't you Variable Length Subnet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Variable Length subnetting` is the process by which you'd divide up the LAN adress into segments.

I have a previous answer that may assist you in the task. You can find it [here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8245/how-to-separate-a-network-in-3-subnetworks/8247#8247)

Answer (score -1):

No. The problem is that based on your subnet any devices on the network will bypass the default gateway and communicate directly with their peer. If you want to establish a DMZ in this manner, a subnet update on each client is mandatory.

Comment: Two words: Private Vlan

Comment: Yeah, that would do it..., though an extra router is required.

Comment: not really, put a firewall in bridge / transparent mode and set it up so the clients can *only* talk to the outside interface of the firewall